# LoaderCallbacks dosen't update ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm writing a small app that has a sqlite database. I have a list view in my main
activity. I'm using a cursor adapter to show the items on the list and it works fine. every time i open the app the list has all the required info.When I'm trying to use LoaderCallback in order to update the list view every time the database is changed, but the list view only changes when I close and reopen the app.

here is the activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

private CursorAdapter taskItemListCursorAdapter;
private ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //testReset(getApplicationContext());

    //set list to show items
    taskItemListCursorAdapter = new CursorAdapterListIem(getApplicationContext(),null);
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView_list_of_tasks);
    listView.setAdapter(taskItemListCursorAdapter);
    this.getLoaderManager().initLoader(1, null,this );




    //getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(DBContract.TASKS_TABLE_URI,false,taskItemListCursorAdapter.registerDataSetObserver(null));

   //this.createDBtest();

    //bind listener new task
    FloatingActionButton newGoalButton = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.main_activity_floatingButton_add_new_goal);
    newGoalButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent addNewGoalIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),CreateNewGoal.class);
            getApplicationContext().startActivity(addNewGoalIntent);
        }
    });

    //listView listeners
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent goalTimerIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),GoalTimer.class);
            goalTimerIntent.setData(Uri.withAppendedPath(DBContract.TASKS_TABLE_URI,String.valueOf(id)));
            getApplicationContext().startActivity(goalTimerIntent);
        }
    });

    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            final long finalId=id;

            //create listner for yes or no
            DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch (which){
                        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                            //Yes button clicked
                            getContentResolver().delete(Uri.withAppendedPath(DBContract.TASKS_TABLE_URI,String.valueOf(finalId)),null,null);
                            break;

                        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                            //No button clicked
                            break;
                    }
                }
            };

            //create new alert listener
            AlertDialog.Builder deleteDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            deleteDialog.setTitle("Delete Goal");
            deleteDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this goal?");
            deleteDialog.setPositiveButton("YES",dialogClickListener);
            deleteDialog.setNegativeButton("NO",dialogClickListener);
            deleteDialog.create();
            deleteDialog.show();

            return false;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public Loader onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    return new CursorLoader(getApplicationContext(),DBContract.TASKS_TABLE_URI,null,null,null,null);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    if (loader==null) {
        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(DBContract.TASKS_TABLE_URI,null,null,null,null);
        taskItemListCursorAdapter = new CursorAdapterListIem(this, c);
    }
    else
        taskItemListCursorAdapter.swapCursor(data);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader loader) {
    taskItemListCursorAdapter.swapCursor(null);
}
}
```

the layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.ariel.weeklytimer.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView_list_of_tasks"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" />

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/main_activity_floatingButton_add_new_goal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_add_circle_black_48dp"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Are you calling `ContentResolver#notifyChange()` appropriately in your `ContentProvider`?

Comment: i think so, my code:   
getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(DBContract.TASKS_TABLE_URI,null);
i have in the end of the insert,update and delete

Answer (score 0):

`onLoadFinished()` try to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter.

```
taskItemListCursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```